# Count related entities without loading them, non-generic way

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, generics, entity-framework-6

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#queryCount) I learned how to count related entities without loading them. The problem is I have no entity type at compile-time. My case:

```
var postCount = context.Entry(someObject)   // someObject received from somewhere
                      .Collection(somePropertyString) 
                      .Query()              // and here I got a non-generic IQueryable
                      .Count();             // which has no Count method
```

If I'm trying to `.Query().Cast<object>().Count()` I'm getting run-time exception at this line:

> System.NotSupportedException occurred   HResult=-2146233067
>   Message=Unable to cast the type '...' to type
>   'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive
>   or enumeration types.   Source=EntityFramework

So, how to count related entities without loading them, if I has no entity type at compile-time?

Comment: for me you have to use reflection to get a `Expression<Func<TEntity, ICollection<TElement>>>` to be able to use the generic version of `Collection` that will allow you use `Count()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using reflection is an option. This extension method helped me:

```
public static int Count(this IQueryable q)
{
    return (int)q.Provider.Execute(
        Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable),
            "Count",
            new[] { q.ElementType },
            new[] { q.Expression }));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also write:

```
int count = context.Blogs.Single(blog=> blog.Id = yourCriteriaId).Posts.Count();
```

this would also not load the Object.

It would produce some SQL statement like this(simplified):

```
Select Count(*) from Post where Post.BlogID = 3
```

Comment: I don't know if it is a `Blog` or something else. I've edited question, it was a little bit misleading

Comment: you must know, because in your sample you assume that your not so unknown type has a `Posts` property.

Comment: @tschmit007 it was copy-pasted from msdn example, now it is corrected